# Error Control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: objective-c

When we try to run the game, the error appears.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 72, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height -72)];
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = FCBoundaryCategory;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = FCPlayerCategory;

    _gameState = FCGameStateStarting;
    _score = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is objective-c and I'm not well versed with it, but I'd guess it's the same as in c or c++: You are missing a `return` statement.

Comment: I would suggest reading about designated initializers. You're missing other important parts of a typical `init` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your method has a return type of `id`, so it has to return a value. You're probably missing the line `return self;` at the end of the method.

Comment: This is an `init` method. It needs more work than just adding the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler prints the error because you're not returning an `id` (an object reference), but the method is declared to return an `id`.  But there are several other problems with this method.

An `init` method must call a `super init` method, assign the result of the super call to `self`, check that it's not `nil`, and return `self`.  Also, modern style is to declare the return type of an init method as `instancetype`.  Thus:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 72, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height -72)];
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = FCBoundaryCategory;
        self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = FCPlayerCategory;

        _gameState = FCGameStateStarting;
        _score = 0;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Read about initializers in [*Cocoa Core Competencies*: Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH21-SW1).

Comment: FYI - I suggest changing the `if` statement one of two ways. It's dangerous to use `=` in an `if` statement (it's a common typo when `==` was meant). 1) Use an extra set of parentheses or 2) Split to two lines. Option #2 seems to be Apple's latest preferred approach.

Comment: The way I wrote is a common idiom.  So common that clang has a special case to *not* warn about it.

Comment: It is also exactly the syntax used in the documentation I linked.

Comment: Unless I'm thinking of a different warning, it requires using an extra pair of parentheses to avoid getting a warning about using assignment in a condition.

Comment: The `-Wparentheses` warning warns about assignments in conditionals (unless the assigments have extra parens), but has a **special case** to not warn about this kind of assignment to self.  You need `-Widiomatic-parentheses` to warn about this case.  See `Sema::DiagnoseAssignmentAsCondition` in [`SemaExpr.cpp`](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Sema/SemaExpr.cpp?revision=218640&view=markup#l12880).